# What is the purpose of prefixing a new Date with the unary `+` operator?

Tags: javascript

I am porting some javascript code (not my strongest language) and came across this:

`Common._nowStartTime = +(new Date());`

`Common` is a module and `nowStartTime` is a property of that module. I'm not sure what the right hand of the expression means? Why prefix with the unary `+` operator?

Comment: To convert it to a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_2):

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to convert it into a number, if it isn't already.

It is commonly used as a shorthand for converting a value to a number. The conversion takes place by calling the value's [`.valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf). From MDN:

> The shorthand notation is prefixing the variable with a plus sign: +"5"

`Date` implements its own `Date.prototype.valueOf()` documented [here:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf)

> This method is functionally equivalent to the Date.prototype.getTime() method.

So the result is effectively a shorthand for this code:

```
Common._nowStartTime = new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: Thank you Klaycon. That's an extremely clear explanation.

Answer (score -1):

the expression `+(new Date())` is the same as `Number(new Date)` so basically you are converting the date to a number timestamp

`Common` is an object so `_nowStartTime` is a property of Common